# What is the Issue with this Convert() in this SQL Query Against MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, sqlanywhere

I am converting some SQL statements now that we're running against MariaDB instead of SQL Anywhere. In one of the queries, I'm getting an error on this line:

```
select convert(char, c.dob, 1) as "DOB"
```

Specifically, this is the error that is produced:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'c.dob, 1) as "DOB",

My understanding is that this "convert" is trying to produce a value of type "char" from the "dob" value, which is currently of type `date`.

What would the issue be in this case? Does it have to do with the way MariaDB handles dates differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONVERT()` has only 2 arguments:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/convert/

And the datatype is second.

Furthermore, if `c.dob` is any type of date or time, then you do not need any conversion function.  It will automatically produce a string in that context.